# sum multiple conditions of list of dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am fairly new to coding. Wondering if you smart peeps can help me out.

I have a list of dictionaries

```py
cars = [
    {"car": "honda", "cost": "500", "color": "white", "year": "2017"},
    {"car": "honda", "cost": "300", "color": "black", "year": "2019"},
    {"car": "honda", "cost": "600", "color": "white", "year": "2020"},
]
```

How can I create a sum for honda white which would be equal 2

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a basic count method. Try this:

```
>>>carList = [("honda","white"),("honda","black"),("honda","white")]
>>>carList.count(("honda","white"))
>>>2
```

Answer (score 1):

The most basic answer would be

```py
ans = 0
for d in cars:
    if d['car'] == 'honda' and d['color'] == 'white':
        ans += 1
print(ans)  # 2
```

More pythonically, You might want to use list comprehsnsion.

```
honda_whites = [d for d in cars if d['car'] == 'honda' and d['color'] == 'white']
print(len(honda_whites)  # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` to keep a count of the entries. One issue is that a dict is not hashable and therefore cant be used as a key to a hash table based data structure like `Counter`. So instead we can use tuples as keys. We will just use the dict values and convert them to a tuple.

It might look something like this.

```
from collections import Counter

lod = [
    {"car": "honda", "color": "white"},
    {"car": "honda", "color": "black"},
    {"car": "honda", "color": "white"}
]

c = Counter(tuple(v.values()) for v in lod)
print(c[('honda', 'white')])
print(c[('honda', 'black')])
print(c[('honda', 'blue')])
```

The output of running this is

```
2
1
0
```

Comment: Thank you!! Does this work if lets say the dictionary has 3 variables instead of 2?                        lod = [
    {"car": "honda", "cost": "500", "color": "white",  "year": "2017"},
    {"car": "honda", "cost": "300", "color": "black",  "year": "2019"},
    {"car": "honda", "cost": "600", "color": "white,  "year": "2020"},
]

Comment: Yes that should be no problem. This does rely on the dict entries being in a consistent order so might not work well on older python versions without sorting the dict values before creating the Counter.